# How create dynamic insert if not exists (no of columns and values vary) for postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, dynamic, insert, psycopg2

I use python 2.7 + Psycopg2 2.6 to insert data into a Postgresql 9.4 database, which is working fine on a very basic level. Have created some dynamic INSERT-queries, which take different sets of columns and values from a dictionary (`input_cols`):

```
sql_template = "insert into tbl ({}) values %s"
sql = sql_template.format(', '.join(input_cols.keys()))
params = (tuple(input_cols.values()),)
cur.execute(sql, params)
```

Correct SQL generated:

```
insert into tbl (col1, col2, ...) values ('val1', 'val2', ...)
```

Would now like to use dynamic SQL generation also for some INSERT if NOT EXIST queries, but as 'cur.execute(sql, params)' above outputs a value list enclosed by '()' I cannot get it to work:

```
sql_template = "insert into tbl ({}) select %s where not exists (select id   
from tbl where id = %s)"
sql = sql_template.format(', '.join(input_cols.keys()))
params = (tuple(input_cols.values()), input_cols['col1'])
```

Incorrect SQL generated:

```
insert into tbl (col1, col2) select ('val1', 'val2') 
where not exists (select col1 from tbl where id = 'val1')
```

How can I output `('val1', 'val2')` without `()` so that I can use it in a `SELECT xxx, xxx WHERE NOT EXISTS` query?

Answer (score 1):

Use `from (values...`

```
input_cols = {'col1':'val1','col2':'val2'}
sql_template = """
    insert into tbl ({})
    select *
    from (values %s) s
    where not exists (
        select id   
        from tbl
        where id = %s
    ) 
"""
sql = sql_template.format(', '.join(input_cols.keys()))
params = (tuple(input_cols.values()), input_cols['col1'])
print cursor.mogrify(sql, params)
```

Output:

```
insert into tbl (col2, col1)
select *
from (values ('val2', 'val1')) s
where not exists (
    select id   
    from tbl
    where id = 'val1'
)
```

Comment: Great :-) Thanks so much for this, Clodoaldo Neto!